# Normalizing complex values in NumPy / Python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, normalization, complex-numbers, activation-function

I am currently trying to normalize complex values.. 
as i don't have a good way of doing this, i decided to divide my dataset into two, consisting of data with only the real part and data only with the imaginary part.

```
def split_real_img(x):
    real_array = x.real
    img_array = x.imag
    return real_array, img_array
```

And then normalize each separately with

```
def numpy_minmax(X):
    xmin =  X.min()
    print X.min()
    print X.max()
    return (2*(X - xmin) / (X.max() - xmin)-1)*0.9
```

after the normalization, is the both dataset supposed to be merged, such that it returns into one data set with complex values?, but how do I do that?

The data normalization is done, such that I can use tanh as activation function, which operates in the ranges -0.9 to 0.9 => which is why I need to the data set to be normalized into these ranges.

Comment: You can create a complex array by summing the two components (with `1j` multiplier): `np.allclose(x.real + 1j*x.imag, x)`.  Or you can express it as a dot product `np.dot([1,1j],[x.real,x.imag])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, two steps would be involved :

- Offset all numbers by the minimum along real and imaginary axes.
- Divide each by the max. magnitude. To get the magnitude of a complex number, simply use `np.abs()`.

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
def normalize_complex_arr(a):
    a_oo = a - a.real.min() - 1j*a.imag.min() # origin offsetted
    return a_oo/np.abs(a_oo).max()
```

**Sample runs for verification**

Let'start with an array that has a minimum one of `[0+0j]` and two more elements - `[x1+y1*J]` & `[y1+x1*J]`. Thus, their magnitudes after normalizing should be `1` each.

```
In [358]: a = np.array([0+0j, 1+17j, 17+1j])

In [359]: normalize_complex_arr(a)
Out[359]: 
array([ 0.00000000+0.j        ,  0.05872202+0.99827437j,
        0.99827437+0.05872202j])

In [360]: np.abs(normalize_complex_arr(a))
Out[360]: array([ 0.,  1.,  1.])
```

Next up, let's add an offset to the minimum element. This shouldn't change their magnitudes after normalization -

```
In [361]: a = np.array([0+0j, 1+17j, 17+1j]) + np.array([2+3j])

In [362]: a
Out[362]: array([  2. +3.j,   3.+20.j,  19. +4.j])

In [363]: normalize_complex_arr(a)
Out[363]: 
array([ 0.00000000+0.j        ,  0.05872202+0.99827437j,
        0.99827437+0.05872202j])

In [364]: np.abs(normalize_complex_arr(a))
Out[364]: array([ 0.,  1.,  1.])
```

Finally, let's add another element that is at twice the distance from offsetted origin to make sure this new one has a magnitude of `1`  and others are reduce to `0.5` -

```
In [365]: a = np.array([0+0j, 1+17j, 17+1j, 34+2j]) + np.array([2+3j])

In [366]: a
Out[366]: array([  2. +3.j,   3.+20.j,  19. +4.j,  36. +5.j])

In [367]: normalize_complex_arr(a)
Out[367]: 
array([ 0.00000000+0.j        ,  0.02936101+0.49913719j,
        0.49913719+0.02936101j,  0.99827437+0.05872202j])

In [368]: np.abs(normalize_complex_arr(a))
Out[368]: array([ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ])
```

Comment: @IamnotFat Normalize usually mean `0 to 1.0`. Please add the details into the question that you want a range from `0.9 to -0.9`.